# Comparing list elements in R

Tags: r, list, compare

I have created two list, the fist named list1 having 4 elements containing 4 bits and the second list2 containing 1 element with 4 bits. I want to compare the lists and if any element in list1 is same as the only element in list2, then i want to delete the element from list1. I've implemented the following code but not getting the correct result.

```
list1<-c()
n<-4
#Creating list1 with 4 vectors having 4 bits each
for(i in 1:5)
{
  rndno<-round(runif(1, 1, 2^n -1),0)
  bn<-bin(rndno)
  pad<-rep.int(0,n-length(bn))
  bn<-c(pad,bn)
  list1<-rbind(list1,bn)
}
list2<-c()
rndno<-round(runif(1, 1, 2^n -1),0)
bn<-bin(rndno)
pad<-rep.int(0,n-length(bn))
bn<-c(pad,bn)
list2<-rbind(list2,bn)
for(i in 1:nrow(k))
{
  if(list2[1,] == list2[i,])
  {
    print(i)
  }
}
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't define the `bin` function in your example, so we can only guess what you would like to achieve. But I think you would like to do something like this:

```
bin <- function(x) {
  i <- 0
  string <- numeric(32)
  while(x > 0) {
    string[32 - i] <- x %% 2
    x <- x %/% 2
    i <- i + 1 
  }
  first <- match(1, string)
  string[first:32] 
}
```

This function converts your decimal number into a binary.

It is also useful to set the random number generator to a given value
in order to make your script reproducible:

```
set.seed(1)
```

Now, this is your code below, although it may not be the most efficient way to create your data. Note also that you named your objects lists, but actually, you're dealing with matrices here.

```
list1<-c()
n<-4
#Creating list1 with 4 vectors having 4 bits each
for(i in 1:5)
{
  rndno<-round(runif(1, 1, 2^n -1),0)
  bn<- bin(rndno)
  pad<-rep.int(0,n-length(bn))
  bn<-c(pad,bn)
  list1<-rbind(list1,bn)
}

# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# bn    0    1    0    1
# bn    0    1    1    0
# bn    1    0    0    1
# bn    1    1    1    0
# bn    0    1    0    0

list2<-c()

rndno<-round(runif(1, 1, 2^n -1),0)
bn<-bin(rndno)
pad<-rep.int(0,n-length(bn))
bn<-c(pad,bn)
list2<-rbind(list2,bn)

# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# bn    1    1    1    0
```

Now, in order to delete the values specified in `list2` from `list1` you compare the rows of the matrix to your target vector and you select only the rows where there is no complete match:

```
list1[apply(apply(list1, 1, function(x) x == list2), 2, function(x) any(x == FALSE)),]

# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# bn    0    1    0    1
# bn    0    1    1    0
# bn    1    0    0    1
# bn    0    1    0    0
```

Comment: did this solution work for you? Did I get it right what the `bin` function was supposed to do? If not, please give the function definition by editing your question, and we can take another look.